# An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (6632) error in Jasper server 6.2

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using Jasper report :- TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.2.0.final
           Jasper server :- JasperReports Server Community Edition (v6.2.0)

I published Report book template Jasper report into Jasper Server. But when I am running report from Jasper Server, I am getting below error

> Error Message
>   An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator.
>   (6632) Error Trace
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSSecurityException: An error has
>   occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (6632) Arguments:
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.validators.Validator.validateSQL(Validator.java:500)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:167)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1129)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:696)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDatasetRun.evaluate(JRFillDatasetRun.java:226)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementDataset.evaluateDatasetRun(JRFillElementDataset.java:238)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillCrosstab.evaluate(JRFillCrosstab.java:610)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:281)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:504)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2026)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:752)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:259)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:119)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:558)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:742)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:58)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:216)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I already updated `security.validation.sql.on=false` in `security-config.properties` file.

But still I am getting this error.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be using some special keywords in your SQL query (such as "with" clause). 
You may need to edit the jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/classes/esapi/validation.properties file.
And edit the line, 
Validator.ValidSQL=(?is)^\s*(select|ADD_NEW_CLAUSE_HERE)\s+^;+$.

And restart the server.

Proving the queries you use will be helpful for a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

**for security reasons(!) I personally would recommend** (using it is quite insecure as described below!) to

1. set this to

   ```
   Validator.ValidSQL=.*
   ```

   or even better

   ```
   #/jasperserver/WEB-INF/classes/esapi/security-config.properties 
   security.validation.sql.on=false
   ```

   so there is **no validity check actually done**.
   Why? Because the previous **(standard regexp) is a quite weak** (and immature - as e.g. preventing `with ... select ...` clauses) **check and may suggest that SQL injection would be prevented in a higher degree**.

**A) if I am NOT concerned about security/SQL injection in my environment** or the cost-value-factor is inefficient (take non-IT budget-responsible people into the boat to decide here!), I would **leave it like this for now**

**B) if I am concerned about security/SQL injection in my environment**, I would recommend to

- read articles about SQL injection and how to prevent it robustly and continually on many necessary levels (e.g. also db user rights) updated for my target databases/ORM frameworks, e.g.

  - [Oracle: Defending Against SQL Injection Attacks](http://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/SQLInjection/index.htm)
  - [Oracle: 12c DBMS_ASSERT Package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_assert.htm#ARPLS231)
  - [PostgreSQL: `quote_*(...)` functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html)
  - ...
- search for better regexp clauses (if existent)? => seems an improper/week method to me only suitable for *"little PHP shop style apps"*

Comment: e.g. `select 'foo;bar'` would also not pass as valid with the standard statement