# Why is the Oracle function SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH working in Jasper Studio, but not on Jasper Server?

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am currently working on a report which use the function [SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions164.htm) to produce a concatenated list. Considering my version of Oracle, I can't use the easier and fancier approach that is [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).

My query is working as intended in my Oracle developper and in my report (in Jaspersoft Studio). The problem is that when I publish the report and try to use it on the server, I receive the following error :

```
2019-03-12 09:37:57,471 ERROR Validator,pool-4-thread-1:496 - Invalid SQL:An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (6632).
```

Cool, an error code, let's read about it : https://laurenthinoul.com/how-to-fix-jasperserver-error-6632/ .

I tried checking for wrong parenthesis and such, but everything is fine and when I take out the SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function from my report and republish it, it works. I would VERY MUCH like to not disable security for the sake of this report.

So, considering the following informations about my current settings :

- JasperSoft studio version : 6.4.0.final
- Jasperserver version : 7.1.0 (build 20180504_1307)
- Oracle version : Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production

Why is the Oracle function SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH working in Jasper Studio, but not on Jasper Server?

Comment: JRS has it is own validator. You can change validation rules to pass check - it is just regexp

Comment: @AlexK Thanks for that advice! If you'd like to post an answer, i'd gladly mark you as the correct one. This helped me find my solution!

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark this question as duplicate of [An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (6632) error in Jasper server 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34430291/876298)